# C++ Vector Crashing

Tags: c++

Evening All,

My following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const char NEWLINE = 0x0D + 0x0A;

int main() {

  int headerCount;
  char response;
  int x = 0;
  int i = 0;
  string header[headerCount];

  cout << "How many columns appear in you file: ";
  cin >> headerCount;
  cout << "There are " << headerCount << " columns in your file? (Y/N): ";
  cin >> response;
  if(response == 'Y'){
    cout << endl << "Okay" << endl;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.csv", ios::binary | ios::out);
    string vals;
    vector< vector<string> > buff;

    // To set values
    while(i != 3){
      vector<string> temp;

      while(x != headerCount){
        if (i == 0){
          cout << "What is header number " << (x + 1) << endl;
        } else {
          cout << "What is person " << i << "'s " << header[x] << ":";
        }
        cin >> vals;
        if (i == 0) header[x] = vals;
        temp.push_back("\"" + vals + "\"");
        if (x != (headerCount - 1)) { temp.push_back(","); }
        x++;
      }
      buff.push_back(temp); // Store the array in the buffer
      x = 0;
      i++;
    }

    //To access values
    for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = buff.begin(); it != buff.end(); ++it){
      //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
      for(vector<string>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt){
        // jt is now a pointer to an integer.
        myfile << *jt;
      }
      myfile << "\r\n";
    }

    myfile.close();

  } else {
    cout << endl << "oh";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Crashes on its fourth iteration.
E.g. value[0][4]

Any ideas? I am reasonably new to vectors. This code causes Code::Blocks to display my application as "not responding". Really Lost at the moment!

I know there are probably plenty of similar posts but I have been trawling the web for hours.

Comment: Debug first before asking here my friend!!

Comment: first of, `int headerCount` is used uninitialized.

Comment: second, you can have variable sized arrays in C++, `string header[headerCount];`.

Comment: third, you are using `std::string` without including its header `#include <string>`.

Comment: run your program using valgrind, I bet it will find the error

Comment: @40two: when you say "you can have variable sized arrays in C++" you actually mean "you **cannot** have variable sized arrays in C++", I guess...

Comment: @DietmarKühl my bad, that exactly what I mean :) (i.e., You can't) missed `'t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must thank  @40two who quickly spotted the main issues.

So add the missing include. Then, define your variable `header` as a vector to allow for dynamic sizing.  However, do this AFTER your `cin` reading,  in order to make sure the variable is initialised and not random:

```
  cin >> headerCount;                   // existing line 
  vector<string> header(headerCount);   // definition in a new place
```

Then it should run without crashing (tested with VC2013)

Comment: @40two has opened my eyes (being the complete newb I am with c++).
However, I have now learned how to use vectors and have fixed my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @40two mentioned, the real issue is that you cannot variable sized arrays in C++. There is huge scope to improve the code significantly. To get you going quickly, see the fixed up code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const char NEWLINE = 0x0D + 0x0A;

int main() {

  int headerCount;
  char response;
  int x = 0;
  int i = 0;

  cout << "How many columns appear in you file: ";
  cin >> headerCount;
  cout << "There are " << headerCount << " columns in your file? (Y/N): ";
  cin >> response;
  if(response == 'Y'){
    cout << endl << "Okay" << endl;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.csv", ios::binary | ios::out);
    string vals;
    vector< vector<string> > buff;

    // To set values
    while(i != 3){
      vector<string> temp;

      while(x != headerCount)
      {
        string header;
        if (i == 0){
          cout << "What is header number " << (x + 1) << endl;
        } else {
          cout << "What is person " << i << "'s " << header << ":";
        }
        cin >> vals;
        if (i == 0)
            header = vals;
        temp.push_back("\"" + vals + "\"");
        if (x != (headerCount - 1)) { temp.push_back(","); }
        x++;
      }
      buff.push_back(temp); // Store the array in the buffer
      x = 0;
      i++;
    }

    //To access values
    for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = buff.begin(); it != buff.end(); ++it){
      //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
      for(vector<string>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt){
        // jt is now a pointer to an integer.
        myfile << *jt;
      }
      myfile << "\r\n";
    }

    myfile.close();

  } else {
    cout << endl << "oh";
  }

  return 0;
}
```